# Trigger file input element with menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the basic Blueimp file upload plugin.

My HTML looks like:

```
 <input id="fileupload" class="button-default" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/php/upload.php" multiple>
```

And my script:

```
function subir(){
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: "json",
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                if(file.error != null){
                    $('#consola').text(file.error);
                };
                myFunction();
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Now, since the page has a menu, I'd like to hide the file input box and use a menu item to trigger the file upload instead.

The menu item has a class of 'item5', so I tried:

```
$('.item5').bind("click", subir);
```

But the function subir doesn't get triggered. It works well when used directly with the file input.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try `$('#fileupload').trigger('click')`

Comment: try $('#fileupload').click()

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onclick="uploadForm.upload.click()" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;"></div>

    <form name="uploadForm">        
        <input name="upload" id="uplaod" type="file" style="display: none"; />
    </form>
```

almost all browsers supports this. But opera do have some problem when the input field is hidden by setting display to none.

You may apply the same logic using javascript to get it work. and also setting visibility to hidden rather than setting display to none.

```
<div id="menu" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;"></div>

    <form name="uf">        
        <input name="upload" id="upload" type="file" style="visibility: hidden;" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("menu").onclick = function (evt) {
            document.getElementById("upload").click();
        }
    </script>
```